# Can I pass variables to blade from Observer in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to send variables to the navigation blade from Observer in Laravel.
What I actually want to do is showing badges on the navigation bar every time created new model data.
I made a variable in the created function in the event observer and want to pass it to the navigation blade.

so I tried like below.

```
      public function created(QnaNonmember $qnaNonmember)
    {
        $qna_new = 1;
        return $this->view('partials.navigation')->with(compact('qna_new'));
    }
```

But in the navigation, it causes an error like below.

```
Undefined variable: qna_new
```

How can I do this in the right way?

Comment: Why not just use the controller?

Comment: Uh.. because I thought I need to use the observer every time the new data created?

Comment: An observer is optional. You use it when there's some logic that should be done every time a resource is created. For example, notify admins every time someone creates a post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass variable to blade from Observers. If you want to pass variable to blade then you will pass from controller.
More info check [Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#observers)

Comment: Okay. I think I need to change my whole logic to do. Thank you for the clear answer.